# Initializing Typescript class values from constructor

Tags: inheritance, constructor, typescript

I'm using TypeScript to create some classes with KnockoutJS, with the data being loaded from some JSON returned by WebAPI.

The problem is I wanted to copy the JSON values into my TypeScript class from the constructor: but if I do this just at the base class, the inherited properties have not been defined and so are not initialised.

Example

We want to create an inventory item from a JSON response:

```
{ Name: "Test", Quantity:1, Price: 100 }
```

I have a base class Product and an inherited class Inventory:

```
export class Product {
  Name = ko.observable("");

  constructor(source) {
    // a utility that copies properties into this instance
    utils.CopyProperties(source,this);
  }

export class Inventory extends Product {
  Quantity = ko.observable(0);
  Price = ko.observable(0);

  constructor(source) {
    super(source); // call base c'tor
    // the quantity and price properties are only now defined
  }
}
```

The properties for Inventory are only created in the JS output code after the *super* constructor call, so do not exist when the Product constructor is executed.

The only solution I can see is to take the initialising value out of the constructor, but I don't really like this approach, although I suspect it's the only option.

```
  var inventoryItem = new Inventory();
  inventoryItem.LoadFrom(source);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of copying properties into the base instance?  Is it bad if Quantity and Price are defined after the copy?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the problem is. The constructor of `Product` should set `Name` from `source` and the constructor of `Inventory` should set `Quantity` and `Price` from `source`

Comment: The problem is you'd have to call copy properties twice: which makes no sense. If you just did it in the Product class, it would only set Name. If you only did it in Inventory, you are not calling it in Product, so anything creating a product won't be initialised

Comment: The problem is that the properties on the `Inventory` object _should_ be defined before the constructor. Instead, the order is 1) `super` call 2) define `Quantity` and `Price`. So after the `super` call, the properties are defined (and overwritten).

If you look at the generated JS, you will see the `super` call comes before the properties are initialized. This seems wrong to me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best I can come up with to allow you to have a base deserialization routine that is called from the constructor is this (modified to remove knockout dependency for testing):

```
class utils {
    public static CopyProperties(source:any, target:any):void {
        for(var prop in source){
            if(target[prop] !== undefined){
                target[prop] = source[prop];
            }
            else {
                console.error("Cannot set undefined property: " + prop);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Product {
  Name = "Name";

  constructor(source) {
    this.init(source);
  }

  init(source){
     utils.CopyProperties(source,this);
  }
}

class Inventory extends Product {
  Quantity;
  Price;

  constructor(source) {
    super(source);
  }

  init(source){
      this.Quantity = 0;
      this.Price = 0;
      super.init(source);
  }
}

var item = new Inventory({ Name: "Test", Quantity: 1, Price: 100 });
```

It *is* odd that the variables are only initialized in the JS after the call to `super()`. Maybe worth [raising a work item on codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)?

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20utils%20%7B%0A%09public%20static%20CopyProperties%28source:any,%20target:any%29:void%20%7B%0A%09%09for%28var%20prop%20in%20source%29%7B%0A%09%09%09if%28target%5Bprop%5D%20!==%20undefined%29%7B%0A%09%09%09%09target%5Bprop%5D%20=%20source%5Bprop%5D;%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09console.error%28%22Cannot%20set%20undefined%20property:%20%22%20+%20prop%29;%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Product%20%7B%0A%20%20Name%20=%20%22Name%22;%0A%0A%20%20constructor%28source%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20//%20a%20utility%20that%20copies%20properties%20into%20this%20instance%0A%20%20%20%20this.init%28source%29;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20init%28source%29%7B%0A%09%20utils.CopyProperties%28source,this%29;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Inventory%20extends%20Product%20%7B%0A%20%20Quantity;%0A%20%20Price;%0A%0A%20%20constructor%28source%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super%28source%29;%20//%20call%20base%20c%27tor%0A%20%20%20%20//%20the%20quantity%20and%20price%20properties%20are%20only%20now%20defined%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20init%28source%29%7B%0A%09%20%20this.Quantity%20=%200;%0A%09%20%20this.Price%20=%200;%0A%09%20%20super.init%28source%29;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20item%20=%20new%20Inventory%28%7B%20Name:%20%22Test%22,%20Quantity:%201,%20Price:%20100%20%7D%29;).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: having an initializer like that is a good alternative. I don't think it's a bug in TypeScript, as I would expect it to work the way it does. It's the dynamic nature of JS: there is no metadata and reflection to work from, unlike C# etc

Answer (score 3):

This approach seems to work for me:

```
/// <reference path="knockout.d.ts" />

export class Product {
    Name: KnockoutObservableString;

    constructor(source) {
        this.Name = ko.observable(source.Name);
    }
}

export class Inventory extends Product {
    Quantity: KnockoutObservableNumber;
    Price: KnockoutObservableNumber;

    constructor(source) {
        super(source);
        this.Quantity = ko.observable(source.Quantity);
        this.Price = ko.observable(source.Price);
    }
}

var item = new Inventory({ Name: "Test", Quantity: 1, Price: 100 });
```

Comment: Thanks.. that would work too but once you start to add a lot of variables it makes for tedious coding. I'll try JcFX's idea first

Answer (score 0):

@JcFx

this variable test always undefined before it's value assigned.

> `if(target[prop] !== undefined){`

you might want to make this if statement always 'true', or use this instead:

```
for (const prop of Object.keys(source)) {
  this[prop] = source[prop];
}
```

it's about forin, see this link:
https://github.com/angular/tsickle/issues/125